# Alternative to ASP.NET Ajax framework in aspx front end

Tags: ajax, wcf, json

I'm developing some CRUD screens for retrieving/updating various items using .NET 3.5 and aspx forms. I am using a WCF service to connect to the back end which is Oracle. I want to use Ajax but I'd rather not use the MS Ajax framework as I want the client pages to be as light and fast loading as possible.

The WCF service will be returning and accepting custom List<> objects. I have used jQuery to return json data in the past but the WCF bindings will be netTcpBinding and it doesn't seem possible to return json from this type of endpoint. As far as I can see json needs wsHttpBinding.  So

1. Can jQuery read and use standard List type objects returned from WCF?
2. Is there another ajax library that can work with this type of object
3. Is it possible to return jsn from a netTcpBinding endpoint?
4. Is this a good approach to take or is there a better way?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use a binding that doesn't allow JSON? If not, I'd change the binding to one that does allow JSON, and just use jQuery AJAX.

Otherwise, if you have to use a binding which doesn't allow JSON, what other data types does it allow? If you can still return XML, jQuery can still be used for XML responses.

Comment: Hi Samo, have to use netTcpBinding as it's company policy. So you're saying there's no way to get json from netTcpBinding? Is it possible to use the results of a method that returns a generic List<>,  e.g. List<Customer>?

Comment: @Ciaran: I actually know nothing of this binding, so you will have to search the APIs (or ask someone else) to see if you can return JSON. However, if it's WCF web service then I would think it has to be serializable in SOME format. If it can do XML then you're fine with jQuery, or any other JavaScript for that matter, since an AJAX request is really an XMLHttpRequest. However, I found some more information on the topic on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441775/wcf-net-tcp-bindings-message-formats-and-security-questions

Answer (score 0):

I also provide an Open Source WCF alternative in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net), a modern, code-first, DTO-driven, WCF replacement web services framework encouraging code and remote best-practices for creating DRY, high-perfomance, scalable REST web services.

It has automatic support JSON, JSONP, CORS headers as well as form-urlencoded/multipart-formdata. The [Online Demos](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/) are a good start to look at since they all use Ajax.

In addition, there's no XML config, or code-gen and your 'write-once' C# web service provides all JSON, XML, SOAP, JSV, CSV, HTML endpoints enabled out-of-the-box, automatically.

It includes [generic sync/async service clients](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#clients) providing a fast, typed, client/server communication gateway end-to-end.